# How to convert dictionary to attr-child class objects?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, classification, decision-tree

I have a dict which has a tree-like structure. 
I want this to be converted into attribute-child relationship defined by my constructor.

This is what my class looks like -

```
class DecisionNode:

# A DecisionNode contains an attribute and a dictionary of children. 
# The attribute is either the attribute being split on, or the predicted label if the node has no children.
def __init__(self, attribute):
    self.attribute = attribute
    self.children = {}
```

You can find my code here - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/karthikkolathumani/Machine-Learning-Models/master/id3.py

This is a dummy method which mimics what I actually need to do with my dictionary object -

```
def funTree():
    myLeftTree = DecisionNode('humidity')
    myLeftTree.children['normal'] = DecisionNode('no')
    myLeftTree.children['high'] = DecisionNode('yes')
    myTree = DecisionNode('wind')
    myTree.children['weak'] = myLeftTree
    myTree.children['strong'] = DecisionNode('no')
    return myTree
```

Sample output is something like (example) -

```
 wind = weak
     humidity = normal:  no
     humidity = high:  yes
 wind = strong:  no
```

Dict object sample -

```
{'outlook': {'sunny': {'temperature': {'hot': 'no', 'mild': {'humidity': {'high': 'no', 'normal': 'yes'}}, 'cool': 'yes'}}, 'overcast': 'yes', 'rainy': {'temperature': {'mild': {'humidity': {'high': {'wind': {'weak': 'yes', 'strong': 'no'}}, 'normal': 'yes'}}, 'cool': {'humidity': {'normal': {'wind': {'weak': 'yes', 'strong': 'no'}}}}}}}}
```

My current result looks like this where I use **selfattr**

```
outlook =
        sunny =
                temperature =
                        hot = no
                        mild =
                                humidity =
                                        high = no
                                        normal = yes
                        cool = yes
        overcast = yes
        rainy =
                temperature =
                        mild =
                                humidity =
                                        high =
                                                wind =
                                                        weak = yes
                                                        strong = no
                                        normal = yes
                        cool =
                                humidity =
                                        normal =
                                                wind =
                                                        weak = yes
                                                        strong = no
```

Comment: You should give a small example of the data you want to convert from a dict to `DecisionNode` object.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen added the information

Comment: I really have a hard time understanding your data. How can `wind -> weak` point to `humidity`, while `wind -> strong` has a `no` value in it?  (from your `funTree()` example)

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen that is just an example to demonstrate the output that I need.

Comment: I believe there's a problem in your `DecisionNode` class, it's not suitable for representing this data. Can you show me how you would manually create this as `DecisionNode` objects: `'cool': { 'humidity': { 'normal': { 'wind': { 'weak': 'yes', 'strong': 'no' } } } }`

Comment: If the root node would be `tree = DecisionNode('cool')`, how would you add the first child, the `DecisionTree('humidity')`? The only logical conclusion for me is to copy the attribute's name as a key like this: `tree.children['humidity'] = DecisionTree('humidity')`, but that's not what you're doing in your `funTree()` example.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen hope my current output makes things a bit clear for you.

Comment: That doesn't explain how you can model it using the `DecisionNode` class. If we have `tree = DecisionNode('outlook')`, how do you add `sunny` to this? Is it `tree.children['sunny'] = ...`? But why isn't `sunny` a `DecisionNode` then? I understand your example data, I don't understand how your class is supposed to be used to model that data.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen If outlook is the root node, then sunny, overcast and rainy are child attributes to the root node outcast. Each of these children are a dictionary which further split into sub-children. For example, rainy has a child Temperature which has its own children(a dictionary)  mild and cool.

Comment: Why is "temperature" a `DecisionNode`, but "rainy" is a dictionary key? How do you make this logical decision, and better yet, why are they different from each other? Are you sure you don't want to [use lists for your `children`](https://pastebin.com/q7npLpY2) instead of [using a dict](https://pastebin.com/ybDqdCQF)?

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen A decision is being made on the fact if it is rainy. Then check what the temperature can hold two different attributes hence it becomes a decision node.
I am really not worried about the children being a dict or a  list.

Comment: Right, where does your data come from? Can you affect the structure of the "dict object sample"? Using something like JSON with proper object notations would be much better format than this.